# Universal Windows Application fails to build in Release with ReactiveUI

Tags: reactiveui, .net-native

Repro steps:

- Create a blank Universal Windows Application.
- Add the ReactiveUI package (latest version 10.1.6)
- Change the configuration to Release
- Change the platform to x86 or x64.
- Build the application.
- You should get an error like this:

> error : ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.7-rel-27913-00\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe
>   @"C:\Users\JMN\source\repos\App6\App6\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\App6.rsp"'
>   returned exit code 1

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the whole program optimizer running out of memory. You can run that portion of our tools in 64 bit mode by adding this to your project:

```
<Use64Bitcompiler>true</Use64Bitcompiler>
```

Because .NET Native is a whole program optimizer, it takes a while for the compiler to chew through things but I'm able to build your repro successfully with this flag enabled.

Certainly let me know if you discover otherwise. That would be very interesting.

Comment: Thank you @MattWhilden ! This suggestion is still valid in 2021 with ReactiveUI several versions up (using 13.3.2) and should be marked as an answer.